# How to delay jump to syncronize with an animation ?

Tags: unity

I'm using Unity and First Person Controller. 
If i press the jump button, my charachter jump immediately. I want,instead, that jump movement starts after (for instance) 1 second, to be syncronized with a jumping animation I trigger.

How to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add delays with [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

```
IEnumerator Jump() {

    //code for starting the animation, however you are doing it
    anim.SetTrigger("Jump");

    //leave code and come back after a second
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    //your code for jumping
    rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpPower);
}
```

You then call this with `StartCoroutine(Jump());`. While the coroutine is waiting,
the game will continue to do other things, like updating animations.